# Unpermitted parameter ActiveAdmin Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I both added username on signup page form and added the same name table column on MySQL database, however, when I click the sign up button, the error message appears and it's never inserted into the table: the rest of the data, email and password, is inserted properly.

Here is the error message:

> Unpermitted parameter: :username

NOTE: username data is surely transmitted as POST parameter.

Although I've tried a lot, such as adding permit_params on controller etc, they've never worked well.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

My brief environment is below.

ruby 2.4.1p11
Rails 5.1.6
ActiveAdmin 1.3
Devise 4.4.3

Thank you.

Comment: add some code from controller and how u trying to permit params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add to ApplicationController?

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
end
```

Comment: Great! Could you please accept my answer in this case?